# PDO bindParam issue about LIMIT

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a issue about PDO.
This code block is worked

```
$MyQuery = $db->prepare("UPDATE project
SET
PeopleId=:PID,
UserId=:UID
WHERE
PeopleId=:PeopleId
AND
UserID=:UserID
AND
(
                alpha = 0
                OR alpha IS NULL
            )  LIMIT ".$Adet);

            $MyQuery->bindParam(":PID", $PID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $MyQuery->bindParam(":UID", $UID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $MyQuery->bindParam(":PeopleId", $PeopleId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $MyQuery->bindParam(":UserID", $UserID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $MyQuery->execute();
```

But it didnt work.

```
$MyQuery = $db->prepare("UPDATE project
SET
PeopleId=:PID,
UserId=:UID
WHERE
PeopleId=:PeopleId
AND
UserID=:UserID
AND
(
                alpha = 0
                OR alpha IS NULL
            )  LIMIT :Count");

            $MyQuery->bindParam(":PID", $PID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $MyQuery->bindParam(":UID", $UID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $MyQuery->bindParam(":PeopleId", $PeopleId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $MyQuery->bindParam(":UserID", $UserID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $MyQuery->bindParam(":Count",$Count, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $MyQuery->execute();
```

Where is my fault ? I couldn't find anything. I guess there is a mistake. I converted the $Count to Integer but it is not worked again .
Can anyone help me about this issue ?

Comment: Check for errors after you execute. Try converting `$Count` to int (`(int) $Count`)

Comment: I try it sir, but i didn't get any error.

Comment: When `PDO::prepare()` errors, it doesn't throw an exception or raise an error by default (unfortunately, IMHO).  `var_dump($db->errorInfo())` after the failure for more information.

Comment: There is not any db errors. @alttag

Answer (score 0):

force the $Count var to be an intger,

```
$MyQuery->bindParam(":Count", (int) $Count, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

mabye trim too: (edited after comment of Muhammed Almaz tnx :D)

```
$Count = trim($Count)    
$MyQuery->bindParam(":Count", (int) $Count, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Comment: Only variables can be passed by reference

Comment: didn't check it but I think you right I will Edit it

Comment: doesn't worked :( my Php version is 5.7 it is a issue ?